# Partial Authentication after expired token

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm fairly new to Oauth and I am wondering if a specific flow is supported by any of the Oauth flows. I want to be able to identify a user and allow that user to perform unsecure actions even after their token has expired. The user would only be forced to  reauthenticate if they request to perform a secure operation.  I currently do not see any flow that will support this.

I have thought of the following solution using refresh tokens but not sure I am possibly violating any oauth patterns or if there is a better way.

1) Issue access token for X amount of time. Lets say 2 hours. 
2) Upon token expiration, refresh token is used to get a new access token. The new token will contain a claim that identifies that the user only has unsecure access.
3) If secure resource is requested, request will be denied with a 401 response code indicating that the token is invalid.
4) Application will have to ask for user credentials in order to receive a new access token.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really up to the interaction between the Resource Server and the Client and certainly with the boundaries of standard OAuth 2.0 . The only thing that OAuth 2.0 standardizes in that interaction is the way in which the access token is presented. All other behavior is left up to the application implementor.

The Resource Server would allow access to unsecure resources/operations regardless of the validity of the access token, or even if there's no access token presented at all. Only upon accessing a secured resource the flow would would as you describe.

I don't see value in producing access tokens that identifies "unsecure access". That token would have the same semantics as an expired token or no token at all, so there's no need for an access token to cover that case.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. The middleware that I was using to help validate the bearer tokens was not setting the identity of the request if the token was expired. I think a better solution will be to modify the middleware to create an identity for the request with limited permissions.  Thanks for the feedback.